# SQL: FIlter rows by direction

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with 2 column date (timestamp), status (boolean).
I have a lot of value like:

```
| date                      | status    |
|-------------------------- |--------   |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:21.125Z  | true      |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:22.125Z  | true      |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:23.125Z  | true      |
....
```

I need to get a result like this:

```
| date_from                 | date_to                   | status    |
|-------------------------- |-------------------------- |--------   |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:21.125Z  | 2018-11-05T19:04:27.125Z  | true      |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:27.125Z  | 2018-11-05T19:04:47.125Z  | false     |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:47.125Z  | 2018-11-05T19:04:57.125Z  | true      |
```

So, I need to filter all "same" value and get in return only period of status true/false.

I create query like this:

```
SELECT max("current_date"), current_status, previous_status
FROM (SELECT date as "current_date",
             status as current_status,
             (lag(status, 1) OVER (ORDER BY msgtime))::boolean AS previous_status
      FROM "table" as table
      ) as raw_data
group by current_status, previous_status
```

but in response I get only no more than 4 value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  A typical method uses the difference of row numbers:

```
select min(date), max(date), status
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by status order by date) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by status, (seqnum - seqnum_s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use `LAG` but then you also need a running counter that increments every time the status changes:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT date, status, CASE WHEN LAG(status) OVER (ORDER BY date) = status THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chg
    FROM yourdata
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT date, status, SUM(chg) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS grp
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT MIN(date) AS date_from, MAX(date) AS date_to, status
FROM cte2
GROUP BY grp, status
ORDER BY date_from
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c2209438b0217b4b5ff4800baa9b2e6d)

Comment: yes, it's a great idea to use chg (checker when status change).